# How do you associate custom metadata to an MS Office file and have it persist even after the file closes In VSTO?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, vsto, ms-office, ribbon

I need to store metadata about a Microsoft office file and have it persist even after the file is closed and re-opened. I am using VSTO 2007 and writing an addon for Microsoft Office ribbon. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your metadata looks like a few key/value pairs, you could use [Custom Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa537163%28v=office.11%29.aspx).