# How do I persist file-independent variables in VSTO that can persist even after the Microsoft Office has closed

Tags: c#, vsto, ms-office

I am using VSTO (visual tools for office.) I need to store a variable that is file-independent (so I cannot stored it in a file meta-data as [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889738/how-do-you-associate-custom-metadata-to-an-ms-office-file-and-have-it-persist-eve)) and can persist after Microsoft office has closed and been restarted. How can I do this?

Note
Is there any way built into VSTO? I want registry, XML, or SQL server ce to be the last resort

Comment: can you store it in the registry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a plenty of ways to do so:

1. Store your data as XML serialization in specific file under predefined direcotry (e.g. %appdata% folder).
2. Store your data using web service which provides data storage (your own web service or remote database, etc.).
3. Store data in system registry as values located in predefined registry key.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way built into VSTO? I want registry, XML, or SQL server ce to be the last resort

Comment: I think VSTO is able to operate with regular .NET application .setting files so you can use them too.